# Question about "eigen"

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, hilbert-space

I have a question about terminology.  Consider a spin-1/2 system with eigenspinors of the the $\sigma_3$ Pauli matrix $\big|\uparrow\big\rangle$ and  $\big|\downarrow\big\rangle$.  We have

$$
\hat\sigma_3\big|\uparrow\big\rangle=\frac{1}{2}\big|\uparrow\big\rangle~~,\quad\quad\text{and}\quad\quad\hat\sigma_3\big|\downarrow\big\rangle=-\frac{1}{2}\big|\downarrow\big\rangle
$$

Here is my question: Is the superposition of $\big|\uparrow\big\rangle$ and $\big|\downarrow\big\rangle$ an eigenspinor of $\sigma_3$?  I think the answer is obviously no.  Am I I correct?

$$
\hat\sigma_3\bigg(\big|\uparrow\big\rangle+ \big|\downarrow\big\rangle \bigg)\neq\alpha\bigg(\big|\uparrow\big\rangle+ \big|\downarrow\big\rangle \bigg)
$$

I forget the exact terminology.

Comment: Yes, the answer is no.

Answer (score 2):

First of all your eigenvalue relations are not exactly correct.

$$\hat\sigma_3\big|\uparrow\big\rangle=\big|\uparrow\big\rangle~~,\quad\quad\text{and}\quad\quad\hat\sigma_3\big|\downarrow\big\rangle=-\big|\downarrow\big\rangle$$

You can verify this by working out the simple matrix multiplication.

Now, 
$$\hat\sigma_3\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\big(\big|\uparrow\big\rangle+\big|\downarrow\big\rangle\big)\bigg)=\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\big(\big|\uparrow\big\rangle-\big|\downarrow\big\rangle\big)\bigg)\neq\alpha\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\big(\big|\uparrow\big\rangle+\big|\downarrow\big\rangle\big)\bigg)$$

Hence the superposition of the two eigenstates is not an eigenstate.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In general, a nontrivial superposition of eigenvectors is another eigenvector iff they all have the same eigenvalue, in which case the superposition also has that same eigenvalue. ("Nontrivial" means that none of the coefficients in the linear combination are zero.) In your space the two eigenspinors have different eigenvalues, so their (nontrivial) superposition is not an eigenspinor.

Indeed, many operators are diagonalizable, in which case *any* vector in the Hilbert space can be written as a linear combination of operator eigenvectors, but clearly not every vector in the Hilbert space is an eigenvector of every diagonalizable operator.